# MongoDB: Conditionally delete DB entries depending on changes in linked file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file, express

E.g.: `FileName = Lakshmikantha.html` and `Username` also `Lakshmikantha`. If that `Lakshmikantha.html` file is modified then I want to delete that user from DB.

```
app.js

 app.post('/home',urlencodedParser,function(req1,res1){
 var filname = req1.body.username;
 var str;
   var originalfile;
   var flag;
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydb");


  dbo.collection("users").insert(req1.body, function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("user "+req1.body.username+ " inserted");
  //  db.close();
  });

  dbo.collection("users").find().toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

     res1.render('home',{user:result});

  //  db.close();
  });
  watcher.on('change', function(path1) {
   var filename = path.basename(path1);
   originalfile = pathParse(filename).name;
   str = originalfile.toString();
   console.log(originalfile);
   flag = true;

 });

 db.close();
});

if(flag){
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydb");
dbo.collection("users").remove({"username":str}, function(err, obj) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 document deleted" + str);

  });
  db.close();
});
}
});

/*MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydb");
  //Delete the "customers" collection:
  dbo.collection("users").drop(function(err, delOK) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (delOK) console.log("Collection deleted");
    db.close();
  });
});*/
```

Here I am inserting users to DB through loginpage and if particular filename with that username appears, I want to delete the entry from the DB.

Comment: Tried to rephrase the title as I understood the intention of the question.

Comment: ThankYou! :) @ascripter